# How to tell google that xyz.com & www.xyz.com are same?

Tags: seo, seo-audit

I have my blog and I am checking it's SEO on woorank.com and found that there are some issues with URLs described in the below image that I am getting there.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any specific questions about the fix they suggest in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to redirect your www.domain.com to domain.com or redirect your domain.com to www.domain.com.

Another way to use the canonical meta tag. Most of WP SEO plugins have this setting.